# how to access a property inside an another property in the same class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, object, es6-class

I'm a react noob player, I was just hanging around my code to add some more options to it, now I want to do something that needs accessing a property in the state object from another property inside the same state object, this is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        persons : [
          {name: "parsa", age: 45},
          {name: "cena", age: 98},
          {name: "jamil", age: 23}
        ],
    defaultPersons: [...this.state.persons]
    }
}
```

Here i need to copy the persons property in the defaultPersons property, is it possible ? how can i do that ?

sorry about any confusion, and

Thanks Everyone :)

Comment: What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: `state = ` is already intended for initial state. What's the purpose of defaultPersons? The code can possibly be improved depending on how it's used.

Comment: I'd use the library [`prop-types`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) and put in default props to pass to App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in one step because there's no `this.state.persons` to refer until it was defined, this is chicken-egg situation. This is not specific to class properties, the same problem would appear in other situations:

```
const foo = {
  bar: 1,
  baz: foo.bar // there's no foo at this moment.
};
```

The problem results from the fact that `defaultPersons` shouldn't be a part of the state. It seems to be a constant that is not changed. In this case `defaultPersons` can be a separate property:

```
class App extends Component {
    static defaultPersons = [
      {name: "parsa", age: 45},
      {name: "cena", age: 98},
      {name: "jamil", age: 23}
    ];

    state = {
        persons : [...App.defaultPersons]
    }

    revertToDefaultPersons() {
        this.setState(state => ({
            ...state,
            persons : [...App.defaultPersons]
        }));
    }
}
```

Or just a constant that is defined outside the class. This makes things simpler but may result in lesser testability.

Comment: Man, you are AWESOME, that is what I was looking for, Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can define persons outside of state, and spread the array into the needed places. I will however say that you should really think about why your are doing this. Is there a way you can dry out your code so you don't need two identical objects in state?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const persons = [{key:'value'}, {key:'value'}];
    this.state = {
       persons: [...persons],
       defaultPersons: [...persons],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is simple way to achieve what do you need: initialize `state` in `constructor`

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
         this.state = {
             defaultPersons : [
               {name: "parsa", age: 45},
               {name: "cena", age: 98},
               {name: "jamil", age: 23}
             ]
         };
         this.state.persons = [...this.state.defaultPersons];
     }
}
```

But there are some nuances.

1. State should contain only dynamic information that affects how component looks(since any change in `.state` with `setState` trigger `render()`). Do you really need `defaultPersons` to be part of `.state`? I believe it should be better to set up it directly into `this.defaultPersons` or even `const` outside `this`.
2. Operation you asked for(and my variant above) makes shallow copy. So any mutation of `defaultPersons[1]` may change `persons[1]` item if reference has not been changed yet. And although mutating data in `state` is bad idea by itself I wanted to highlight this thing.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use componentDidMount to update the original state

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        persons : [
          {name: "parsa", age: 45},
          {name: "cena", age: 98},
          {name: "jamil", age: 23}
        ],
    defaultPersons: []
    }

     componentDidMount () {
     this.setState({
     defaultPersons: [...this.state.persons]
    })
  }
}
```